# How can I fill gaps in a dc.js series chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following dc.js [series chart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.seriesChart.html):

```js
var data = [
  {day: 1, service: 'ABC', count: 100},
  {day: 2, service: 'ABC', count: 80},
  {day: 4, service: 'ABC', count: 10},
  {day: 7, service: 'XYZ', count: 380},
  {day: 8, service: 'XYZ', count: 400}
];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [d.service, d.day]; });
var grp = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.count; });
var chart = dc.seriesChart('#graph')
  .width(620)
  .height(175)
  .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).renderArea(true);})
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(grp)
  .seriesAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
  .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 8]))
  .legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(80))
  .render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.css"/>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

It works as expected... but since there are "gaps" in my data, it doesn't look so good. Is there any way to tell dc.js to default to 0 the points where there isn't data for a particular series?

Basically, I want this result, but without having to create a different group for each series and stacking them together myself:

```js
var data = [
  {day: 1, service: 'ABC', count: 100},
  {day: 2, service: 'ABC', count: 80},
  {day: 4, service: 'ABC', count: 10},
  {day: 7, service: 'XYZ', count: 380},
  {day: 8, service: 'XYZ', count: 400}
];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.day; });
var grpABC = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.service === 'ABC' ? +d.count : 0; });
var grpXYZ = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.service === 'XYZ' ? +d.count : 0; });
var chart = dc.lineChart('#graph')
  .width(620)
  .height(175)
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(grpABC)
  .stack(grpXYZ)
  .renderArea(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 8]))
  .legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(80))
  .render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.css"/>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Is there any way to achieve the same with the seriesChart of the first example?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351725/fill-gaps-in-nvd3-js) which might be similar, but they're using NVD3.js and Underscore. We have jQuery, d3.js and dc.js instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ) contains [a section on preprocessing data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted). In this case, you want to ensure that any empty values are filled with zero, and [`ensure_group_bins`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#ensure-that-bins-exist-even-if-there-are-no-values-in-them) is pretty close to what you want.

Here I've adapted it to take the required bins as an array instead of as arguments, because we need to require a lot of bins - the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the services and all the days. Handily, D3v4 contains [d3.cross](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#cross) for exactly this purpose.

Then we just wrap our group with the fake group produced by `ensure_group_bins` and we are off!

Interestingly, this exposes a detail about your data which was obscured before - since the line chart only draws points where it has data, it was previously not clear that service ABC / day 3 is zero.

```js
function ensure_group_bins(source_group, bins) {
return {
    all:function () {
        var result = source_group.all().slice(0), // copy original results (we mustn't modify them)
            found = {};
        result.forEach(function(d) {
            found[d.key] = true;
        });
        bins.forEach(function(d) {
            if(!found[d])
                result.push({key: d, value: 0});
        });
        return result;
    }
};
};
var needed = d3.cross(['ABC', 'XYZ'], d3.range(1,8));

var data = [
  {day: 1, service: 'ABC', count: 100},
  {day: 2, service: 'ABC', count: 80},
  {day: 4, service: 'ABC', count: 10},
  {day: 7, service: 'XYZ', count: 380},
  {day: 8, service: 'XYZ', count: 400}
];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [d.service, d.day]; });
var grp = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.count; });
grp = ensure_group_bins(grp, needed);
var chart = dc.seriesChart('#graph')
  .width(620)
  .height(175)
  .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).renderArea(true);})
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(grp)
  .seriesAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
  .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 8]))
  .legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(80))
  .render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.4/dc.css"/>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon. That's probably the most detailed answer I've ever received on SO. Also thanks for editing the CSS issue in the question :)